# Comedian takes down meltdown video

Tags: copyright

If a comedian has a meltdown on stage & I Youtube that (just the meltdown, no material), can that comedian have said video pulled for copyright reasons?

Comment: [Read the basics first, please](https://law.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/541/i-have-a-question-about-copyright-what-should-i-read-before-i-ask-it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The person who first puts a thing into fixed form holds copyright: if you take a movie of a bird, you hold the copyright to that movie. If the subject of the movie is a human, it is the same. There are some limitations that are outside of copyright, having to do with the right of personality, but that would not be applicable in this context. You might be in breech of contract for having filmed the event, but maybe the venue failed to require you to not record anything (anyhow, again, that isn't copyright).

The comedian can file a takedown notice and probably would not get in trouble for perjury, on the assumption that the comedian wrongly believes that he holds the copyright to anything about him (the DMCA notice doesn't require you to be actually correct in your claim to hold copyright – correctness would eventually be determined by the court). If there is a takedown notice filed, you can file a counter-claim explaining why the comedian does not hold copyright. Then the ISP has to wait a bit (2 weeks) and restore the material, unless the complainant files an action against you in court.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I posted a video about 5 years ago & got a good amount of views. I didn’t start recording until I felt the show was not going to start. He got up & maybe 5 minutes in he starts a fight with a heckler. That’s where the video starts. I really don’t mind if I was in the wrong, but feel with this star trying at a comeback, maybe he’s shaking trees & I may be able to get it re-enlisted. Appreciate the help!